# Alexa account linking by different OAuth providers

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My objective is to read/manage users calendar(Google/Microsoft/Apple) using OAuth access token in my skill. If it is for only one account, I am able to do this. However I wanted to give the user options to choose between different accounts(Google/Microsoft/Apple). I believe we can achieve this using OAuth implicit grant type. But I wanted to use OAuth 'Auth Grant Type' which gives refresh token. So that I don't want to ask the user to link the account again whenever the access token expires(1 hour). Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own web page and give all these OAUth options to the user

Comment: Yes. I thought of that. But where will we give the token uri, client ID and client secret of all the OAuth providers. Usually for single OAuth provider, we give the Amazon provided links as redirect uris and Amazon calls the token uri with client ID and secret what we provided and get the access token, refresh token and store it in their server. My question is how to do handle it for different OAuth providers.